# How to replace element in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: pandas, replace

I have this DataFrame:

```
d = {'col1': ['(-99999.0, -99998.0]', '(-99998.0, 1.0]','(1.0, 10]']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

which looks like this:

```
                   col1
0  (-99999.0, -99998.0]
1       (-99998.0, 1.0]
2             (1.0, 10]
```

I need to replace the square bracket `]` with a round bracket `)`, so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
                   col1
0  (-99999.0, -99998.0)
1       (-99998.0, 1.0)
2             (1.0, 10)
```

How do I do it?

Comment: `df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('\]',')', regex=True)`

Comment: Yes ! thanks ! That answers it !

Comment: df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("]",')'))